# my pygame window opened and closed instantly

Tags: python, class

```
import math
import random
import pygame

# static variables
MAX_ANTS = 100
FPS = 60
HEIGHT = 1080
WIDTH = 1920
SIZE = 5
ANT_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)

Win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,  HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("ANTS")


def move(x, y, speed):
    direction = random.randint(0, 360)
    x += speed * math.acos(direction)
    y += speed * math.asin(direction)
    return x, y


def draw(x, y):
    Win.fill((150, 100, 125))
    center = (x, y)
    pygame.draw.circle(Win, ANT_COLOR, center, SIZE)
    pygame.display.update()

class Ant:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.speed = 3
        self.direction = (360 / MAX_ANTS) * self.id
        self.x = WIDTH/2 + math.acos(self.direction) * SIZE
        self.y = HEIGHT/2 + math.asin(self.direction) * SIZE
        self.size = 5

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main(self.x, self.y, self.speed)


def main(x, y, speed):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        ants = []
        for i in range(MAX_ANTS):
            ants.append(Ant(i))

        x, y = move(x, y, speed)
        draw(x, y)
    pygame.quit()
```

if anyone could find out the hell i did wrong XD i'm new i'd like to learn from my errors so please tell me what i did wrong(if you can)
INFO:There is no errors in my program
i want to make little circle(ANTS) that move around randomly with this code

Comment: When i run your code i get an error maximum recusion. I am not too sure about what you are trying to do with the line `if __name__ == '__main__':`, also, every frame you recreate every ant object. This is not verry efficient

Comment: yes but the objects move so i need to recreate them every time
the line if __name__ == '__main__': is way to code that the code should be run directly and manually (https://youtu.be/g_wlZ9IhbTs)
but even if i get rid off this line still doesnt work